# How to verify Blank Page in Cypress

Tags: cypress

When I redirect to Blank Page I will test this page is blank page but In cypress , I don't know keyword to verify.

this is DOM I will check role if role is not admin, it will don't show anything but role is admin, it will show text This Page Is Correct

I want to create cypress to check if role isn't admin and page is blank page, but I don't have idea to verify this is blank page

"{user?.role !== "admin" ? ( <></> ) : ( <form <> This Page Is Correct </> )}"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3X4p.png)

What keyword I should use to check blank page.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more info on the 'blank page'. Does the DOM show anything? Does the url reflect a blank page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to check exactly what HTML you get in dev-tools (Elements tab) for a blank page, but this will kind-of do what you want to do.

```js
if (user.role !== 'admin' ) {

  cy.get('body')
    .should('not.contain', 'This Page Is Correct')

} else {

  cy.get('body')
    .should('contain', 'This Page Is Correct')
}
```

If you find the text is there for both roles, but is hidden for non-admin, you could add

```js
  .and('not.be.visible')

  ...

  .and('be.visible')
```